# vscode: navigate to file or folder via path from clipboard

Tags: visual-studio-code

In an opened vs code workspace I often find myself in a situation there I have a path (within this workspace) in clipboard that I want to navigate to and do not know any other way than clicking through the directory hierarchy.

Is there any way to navigate the explorer pane to a certain path that I have in clipboard? like an addressbar, i can paste to?

If I have a filepath in clipboard I can hit [ctrl+p][ctrl+v][enter] to open the file and get the explorer showing the path. This does not work with a folder paths (and often I do not want to open the file but go to the directory - and closing it immediately jumps away from the path to now-focussed tabs file location)